# PHP File cannot recover session variable across pages

Tags: php, session, post

Okai, so I attempted to post this a bit earlier, although my question has changed slightly.
I have identified the problem to be in between my login.php (where I assign the $_SESSION value) and my members.php page (where I try to pick up the $_SESSION variable again, but fail to recover it). The way I identified this problem was by running a var dump on session in my members.php file which gave me 0. I also did this after I asign the value in login.php and I got the asigned value as an outcome.
If you help me out I will really appreciate it!

This is my login.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
require('connect.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (isset($username) && isset($password))
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    $result = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($result > 0)
    {
        echo "You have been logged in. <a href='members.php'>Go to the members page</a>";
        $username = $_SESSION['login'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Password is incorrect. Try again.";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "You have to enter your username and password. Try again";
}
?>
```

This is my members.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
    echo "Welcome " .  $login . " | <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: --generic comment about `mysql_*` and `sql injections`--

Comment: No but seriously, I don't see anything under `if($result > 0)` to change the `$_SESSION['login']`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, just want to sort out the basics before I add decryption and SQL prevention... hmmm, so is $_SESSION['login'] not asigned or?

Comment: Under result>0 I see `$username = $_SESSION['login'];`, but that doesn't do anything? Shouldn't it be `$_SESSION['login'] = true;`?

Comment: Hmmmmm, but I need identification of the user on the members.php page...

Comment: What else from `login` (sql table), do you have?

Comment: `DESCRIBE login`, you must have a primary ID column. (I'm guessing)

Comment: I got a connect.php page refered to as required in login.php.... but this works as my username and password is checked properly. I do get the you are logged in value. Oh, yeah, well my primary ID column is all of them, use domain.com as host but I will check again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31062/discussion-between-dave-chen-and-friedbitz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in Chat:

1. Turns out `var_dump(is_writable(session_save_path()));` returned `bool(false)`.
2. The `session_save_path()` was `/var/php_sessions/`.
3. `realpath(dirname(__FILE__));` was `/hermes/bosoraweb124/b185/dom.gjertgjersundcom/public_html`.

I tried moving the session save path -- however for some reason the folder within `public_html` couldn't be written, same with read (couldn't read). In any case, it's a bad idea to have `sessions` in the public folder for everyone to see anyway.

I recommended the OP contact their host provider to run the command of `chmod 766 -R /var/php_sessions/`.

Solved: The staff at his webhost applied the permissions and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Your session "login" variable is not set because you never set it in your login file...

You should specifically set it with $_SESSION['login'] = "blah";

I assume your problem is you meant to set login and not the username when you log in the user...
swap

```
if($result > 0)
    {
        echo "You have been logged in. <a href='members.php'>Go to the members page</a>";
        $username = $_SESSION['login'];
    }
```

with

```
if($result > 0)
    {
        echo "You have been logged in. <a href='members.php'>Go to the members page</a>";
        $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
    }
```

Then you should be able to access your "login" session variable from your member page.

Also on your member page I do not see you set your $login variable. So I assume that would be a blank space and you meant to echo your session login variable with $_SESSION['login'].

Comment: I have tried changing those around a lot Devon, it did not resolve my problem, I am afraid it is more than that.